# Face Recognition integration

Tags: android, face-recognition

I want to integrate Face Recognition in Android.

1) First time user will sign up by scanning face (Will stored on Server/local)

2) Next time when a user tries, it should detect the user from the stored image.

I tried exploring Face Recognition of AWS but ended up with confusion in setting up.

Comment: ML Kit has [Face Detection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces)

Comment: @RonTLV that probably gives Face Detection only. Any idea for Face Recognition?

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways you can do this. 
there is a simple library for this purpose in android called [FaceDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector). you can use that for face detection only.

there are also more advanced libraries like [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/android/) which is available for many languages including java and android. but I recommend if you are not familiar with android NDK or computer vision try sticking with the FaceDetector library.

note that if you start with OpenCV. it is going to be hard for you at first because you are entering a field called computer vision which is a branch of machine learning. and immediately you will feel it that you're walking in a completely new territory

Comment: @  A.easazadeh FaceDetector can be used for detecting not for recognition.